# Addition or IF within a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

```
def front_x(words):
    first = []
    count = 0
    for x in words:
        count+=1
        if x[0] == "x":
            first.append(x)
            words.remove(x)



    print(count)   
    words = sorted(words)
    first = sorted(first)


    return first + words
```

I was testing this with the following lists ["mix", "xanadu", "apple", "aardvark", "xyz"] and ["bbb", "ccc", "axx", "xzz", "xaa"]  and for some reason the counts for both lists are different? I'm troubles-shooting because for some odd reason the function doesn't pick up the "xaa" as triggering the if-statement in the second test case. What I noticed however is that even the count doesn't tie out between the two, and my only theory is that the if statement executes first so then the count addition reflects how many times the if statement isn't triggered.

Comment: **Don't alter a collection (list,...) while iterating over it**...

Comment: Actually I just tried that, and the counts still vary.

Comment: you can use deep.copy(yourlist) to make a copy of it and change the copy

Comment: @HaifengZhang: no need for a deep copy, a shallow one is enough.

Comment: so I amended the code so that I don't change the list but I still get different counts which I find puzzling.                                                                                     def front_x(words):
    first = []
    second = words
    count = 0 
    for x in words:
        count +=1
        if x[0] == "x":
            first.append(x)
            second.remove(x)
  
       
           
 
    second = sorted(second)
    first = sorted(first)
    print (count)
 
    
    return first + second

Comment: You can use `filter()` function...

Comment: second = words doesn't make a new list, just a pointer to the same list. You need a copy() or a slice (:)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You've been told "**don't change a list you are iterating over**" and that will fix your issue.

However, you can simplify this if all you are doing is sorting based on if a word starts with `x` + lexical ordering then you can do something like:

```
>>> a = ["mix", "xanadu", "apple", "aardvark", "xyz"]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[0] != 'x', x))
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

This works because `x[0] != 'x'` is equivalent to `0` when `x[0] == 'x'` and `1` when `x[0] != 'x'`, and tuple ordering forces all `x` words to the front.

If you need to count the number of words that begin with `x` then you can:

```
>>> sum(x[0] == 'x' for x in a)
2
```

Comment: That's definitely true. And I should do that, but right now I'm just trying to figure out the basics of why my counts don't tie out.

Comment: I'm assuming the "**don't change a `list` you are iterating over**" has fixed that issue for you.